# Why island strum works on majority of the songs?

Tags: strumming

I have played many songs with only Island strums. However, I never realized how it works that way?

I worked with 4/4 pattern songs and 3/4 pattern songs. Both the cases, it seems to work.

But how?

Comment: Is it possible your repertoire of songs is made of mostly of songs that work with the island pattern? Are you playing Tool or AC/DC or Led Zeppelin or Muse or Chevelle? Those are just examples of bands whose music probably wouldn’t go as well with an island strumming pattern.

Comment: @todd, hmm. That may be the case too. Thank you.

Comment: As the island strum (as I understand it) is a 4/4 pattern, and many popular songs are in 4/4, It will be possible to make the island strum fit many songs - though it may not be a good fit for the exact rhythmic feel of every 4/4 song. However, it seems hard to imagine how to make it fit a 3/4 song, unless there is a 3/4 version of the island strum I am not aware of..?

Comment: Island strum? Never heard it called that, although I've used it (without the last up-strum) for ever. The last upstrum makes chord changes very quick - or very messy (or maybe open strings). It's 4/4, so will fit with many 4/4 songs, but there will inevitably be some it won't gel with. 3/4, island strum? Not at all sure, so I consider the question is asked under false premises.

Comment: The 4/4 Island Strum pattern cannot work over 3/4 without alteration of some kind. An example of a 3/4 song with which you used this pattern would be helpful.